# sequential command processing with an async io cloud upsert

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous-programming, async

We are new to c# and still trying to grok the async idioms.

We have a windows service that requires us to iterate a list of results queried from a PC database to feed the parse cloud server (which only supports async reads and writes). The results often have to be overridden with new results.

In a legacy java sdk, we simply did:

```
For each result:

do synchronous find
if not found
 create a new object/document
else
 Update the existing object/document
Save synchronously
```

and had no problems.

BTW - our server needs to feed Parse in seconds, not microseconds, though sub second performance would not hurt!

Our current production system used lock() to ensure the read/write stayed synchronized however we suspect **deadlocks are occurring**. A telling fact is that restarting the service processes the command queue just fine!!

Our proposed fix looks like this:

```
  private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

  public async Task ProcessPostedCommandsAsync()
    {
        using (var showContext = new ShowContext())
        {
            var retryCnt = 0;
            var maxRetries = 8;


            var commands = FindCommands(showContext);

            foreach (var command in commands)
            {

                await _mutex.WaitAsync();
                try
                {
                     // read data from the cloud, 
                     // based on data from the cloud, write back to the cloud
                     // mark the command as processed in the database
                     await ProcessCommandAsync(showContext, command);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    GlobalLogger.Logger.Error(e,
                        $"assinging executing task, Exception in Process Commands pkid = {command.Pkid} ");
                    GlobalLogger.Logger.Error($"Retry count = {retryCnt}");
                    retryCnt++;
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    if (retryCnt == maxRetries)
                    {
                        break; // from for
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _mutex.Release();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

We have since modified our code to hopefully address the deadlock problem using the SemaphoreSlim.

With only one command in the database, let's call it Command-A, duplication seems to occur when the command reading loop re-reads Command-A even though Command-A was has already kicked off its cloud read/write.

Everywhere we look says, “DO NOT BLOCK or you will get deadlocks”   and says go async/await all the way.   But if we don’t block in some way we will get race conditions and duplicates.

So we added locks  and we get what seem like deadlocks after hours of processing commands just fine.

This seems like a pretty common use case.

1) Is there an c# idiom we are missing here that loops through a command list to write asynchronously to the cloud but in sequential order without sending duplicates and not creating deadlocks?  We really just want a way to wait for each synchronized command to finish.

2) How can we test this in such a way to prove it works in varying environments.

We really feel like in a **Catch 22** situation.  We need to block to wait for the command to fully process while yet we should not block async code.

Note: We've looked at the following resources and are looking for direction so far.

[Concurancy in C# Cookbook by Stephan Cleary](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=MMaUAwAAQBAJ&source=productsearch&utm_source=HA_Desktop_US&utm_medium=SEM&utm_campaign=PLA&pcampaignid=MKTAD0930BO1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMItMO3qOC13AIVB49pCh29KQCtEAQYASABEgLkx_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CIiKsqrgtdwCFVc_TwodCRMPNw)

[Async/Await Best Practices](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

[Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: Just to be clear for me, does sequential mean order matters? In a lot of contexts it does. Or did you mean simply iterate over a possibly randomly ordered collection?

Comment: Why is "unprocessed command" in quotes? Are you skeptical it is actually unprocessed? Or perhaps it has been processed locally but there is a lag in updating the data source? Please explain.

Comment: @KristianH, yes we need them to be processed in order.

Comment: @JohnWu,  un processed commands were quoted because they were actually being processed asynchronously already.  I clarified the question and look forward to your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, asyncronous tasks behave not much differently than threads, and most the thread intuition should apply to them as well. But you should not use threading primitives (such as locking) which may lock it. If you need to synchronize asyncronous tasks, you can acquire locks asynchnonously: https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/

Actually, if I understand it correctly, as a start, you could run all your code as a single task:

```
public async Task StartProcessing()
{
    DisableStartProcessingUI();
    try {
        foreach (result in results) {
            if(TryFind(result, out Document document)) {
                await Update(document);
            } else {
                await CreateDocumentFromResulit(result);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        EnableStartProcessingUI();
    }
}
```

This runs basically synchronously, and blocks UI which is used to start processing, so that you don't run it again while first request is still executing. So you don't even have to lock it in this case. But if you want to use concurrent requests to `Update()` and `CreateDocumentFromResulit()` then you'd need to use some semaphores as above to avoid accessing same documents.

**Edit**: In your example, should probably be "**await** ProcessCommandAsync(showContext, command);"

Comment: we don't have a UI, we have a windows service.   I've included the proposed code fix bases on your answer and we still get the duplicate writes to the cloud.  We look forward to your inputs.

Comment: If you mean that your `ProcessCommandAsync()` is called twince concurrently it is very strange. Are you sure you are using the same `_mutex` instance in all invocations of `ProcessPostedCommandsAsync()`?

Comment: @max36, By duplication, I mean that the same write command is kicked off twice and before the done processing flag is set in the database for the first command.  Consequently, two duplicate writes are completed.

Comment: @max360, I added the declaration of _mutex in the example code.  It is located in the same class.

Comment: @max360, We really just want a way to "wait" for each synchronized command to finish.  What's the proper way to do that?

Comment: @RayTrask so the second ProcessCommandAsync() is started before another is completed?

Comment: actually, it is called "...Async", doesn't it return `Task`? Them you shoud `await` for it as well

Comment: @max360,  Yes that is correct, the second ProcessCommandAsync() is started before the first one is marked completed.   BTW an Ooops on my last edit, that "await" call got lost in the shuffle, I put it back in.  Sorry for that!  You got my hopes up for a second.  I like it when it is an easy pilot error.

Comment: Well I cannot say then. I believe the locks themselves should be working. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985233/does-semaphoreslim-net-prevent-same-thread-from-entering-block). Check again if your system completes the `ProcessCommandAsync`'s task only after processing is marked as done at server.

Comment: @max360, thanks for reference and all the things to look for.